# render_to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status'

Tags: django, python-2.7, httpresponse

I am running a django application and getting the following error:

```
TypeError at /login

render_to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status'

Request Method:     GET

Request URL:    http://10.107.44.122:8002/login?next=/

Django Version:     1.7.1

Exception Type:     TypeError

Exception Value: render_to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status'

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py in render_to_response, line 23

Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python

Python Version:     2.7.6
```

The only place I could think of where the error might be coming from is :

```
render_to_response('login.html', context, status=status, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

`status` is supposed to be expected keyword for `render_to_response`, then why this error?

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: @solarissmoke it says in the error: 1.7.1

Comment: What is `status` supposed to be anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `render` shortcut instead of `render_to_response`. The `render` method does take a `status` argument in all versions of Django. It's a nicer method to use anyway, because you don't need to supply a `RequestContext`.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    context ={'foo': 'bar'}
    status = 200
    return render(request, 'login.html', context, status=status)
```

Comment: What is the context variable here? Thanks.

Comment: @JasonTyler `context` is a dictIonary of values to add to the template context. I've added an example.

Answer (score 3):

The `status` argument is accepted in Django 1.8, not in 1.7. Compare the documentation for the `render_to_response` methods in [1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response) and [1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response).