# Django 1.7.11 :render_to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'

Tags: python, django

There are a few related questions, such [as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212565/render-to-string-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-status), but the answers do not appear to work.

I have the following in my views.py

```
def pilab(request):
    return render(request, 'pilab.html',{'foo':'bar'})
```

Running this and going to it's corresponding url returns the following error:

```
Traceback:
File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/server/home/views.py" in pilab
  31.     return render(request, 'pilab.html',{'foo':'bar'})
File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  50.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),

Exception Type: TypeError at /pilab/
Exception Value: render_to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

Strangly enough, removing the context string returns virtually the same error:

```
Traceback:
File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/server/home/views.py" in pilab
  31.     return render(request, 'pilab.html')
File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  50.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),

Exception Type: TypeError at /pilab/
Exception Value: render_to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

How can this error be fixed?

Comment: You had a look at RequestContext? Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/5154458/1073606

Comment: @user1. I did now, but I'm uncertain how to use this. I thought the third input for render would automatically be designed for `context_instance`

Comment: @Mitchell van Zuylen Would you please update your code with urls.py as well?